# How to filter data frame by range of row values with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, row, subset

I have a following data frame and i want to filter the data frame that only contains values from 2019-06-01 to 2019-06-30

```
    ds            yhat
1   2015-01-01    -100
2   2015-01-02     250
3   2015-01-03      50
4   …               60
5   2019-06-30     370
```

Comment: Filtering on a *range* really suggests `Date`-class objects (in this case), but the last value in the `ds` column is a string. If they are really `Date` class, then `x[x$ds >= as.Date("2019-06-01") & x$ds <= as.Date("2019-06-30"),]` might work. Both `dplyr::between` and `data.table::between` (depending on your preference) are available, changing this from `dplyr::filter(x, between(ds, as.Date("2019-06-01"), as.Date("2019-06-30"))` or `as.data.table(x)[ between(ds, as.Date("2019-06-01"), as.Date("2019-06-30"), ]`.

Comment: @r2evans good observation, i corrected the example.

Answer (score 0):

Three methods, depending on your R-ecosystem of choice:

```r
### base R
subset(dat, as.Date("2019-06-01") <= ds & ds <= as.Date("2019-06-30"))
#           ds yhat
# 5 2019-06-30  370

### tidyverse
library(dplyr)
dplyr::filter(dat, between(ds, as.Date("2019-06-01"), as.Date("2019-06-30")))
#           ds yhat
# 5 2019-06-30  370

### data.table
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[ between(ds, as.Date("2019-06-01"), as.Date("2019-06-30")), ]
#            ds yhat
# 1: 2019-06-30  370
```

(FYI: the only reason I prepended `dplyr::` to `filter` is that some may try the call without loading `dplyr`, and will find that `stats::filter` behaves much differently. In general, if you `library(dplyr)` then you should be able to do just `filter(dat, ...)`.)

---

Data:

(with `ds` already converted to `Date`-class.)

```r
dat <- structure(list(ds = structure(c(16436, 16437, 16438, NA, 18077), class = "Date"), yhat = c(-100L, 250L, 50L, 60L, 370L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```